# In Chrome, style.fontFamily doesn't work for a barcode font, but className does

Tags: javascript, css, classname

Consider the following html:

```
<style>
.barcode { font-family: 'BC C39 3 to 1 Medium'; }
</style>
<div><span id='spn'>1234567</span></div>
```

The following will set the font to a barcode:

```
<script>
document.getElementById('spn').className = 'barcode';
</script>
```

But The following won't:

```
<script>
document.getElementById('spn').style.fontFamily = 'BC C39 3 to 1 Medium';
</script>
```

Why?

I need to use the style.fontFamily tag, not the className, but this appears to not be possible for some reason.

Comment: Something must be wrong with the value itself. I tried `...style.fontFamily = 'Verdana, Arial';` and it worked fine.

Comment: Standard fonts work just fine. The font is installed on the machine. Since the class definition using the same fonr name works, the font name is not the issue.

Comment: maybe it has to do with the spaces in the font-family name, and that JS treats those different from CSS (?)

Comment: @Johannes The spaces are indeed the problem (more precisly the numbers). But the main difference is that the font is quoted in the CSS part (the value there is `'BC C39 3 to 1 Medium'` with the quotes and not `BC C39 3 to 1 Medium`) and in the JS code the value is `BC C39 3 to 1 Medium` which results in the numbers becoming a problem. The value is treaten the same way in both cases, it is just that the value is acutally different.

Answer (score 1):

I know you already got your answer. But here some explanation why:

If you write `fontFamily = 'BC C39 3 to 1 Medium';` then this equals writing:

```
.barcode { font-family: BC C39 3 to 1 Medium; }
```

On [MDN: Valid family names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-family#valid_family_names) you have this paragraph:

> Font family names must either be given quoted as strings, or unquoted as a sequence of one or more identifiers. This means that punctuation characters and digits at the start of each token must be escaped in unquoted font family names.

So your font name - if written without quotes - is not valid due to the `3` and `1`, if it is not surrounded by quotes. The same is true if you use `style.fontFamily` which is why it has to be:

```
document.getElementById('spn').style.fontFamily = "'BC C39 3 to 1 Medium'";
```

Or why `3` and `1` would need to be escaped (but using quotes is the recommended way).